# How can I join an Advantage ADT table to a DBF table in a single query?

Tags: advantage-database-server

How can I join an Advantage ADT table to a DBF table in a single query?

Answer (score 4):

Create and use data dictionary.  If the tables are both in a data dictionary, then you can join them just fine.

Comment: Any way to do it without using a data dictionary?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it in a single SQL statement without using data dictionary.